# How could I prove that for any two tuples $\left( {{x_1},{y_1}} \right)$ and $\left( {{x_2},{y_2}} \right)$ in $\mathbb R^2$, ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How could I prove that for any two tuples $\left( {{x_1},{y_1}} \right)$ and $\left( {{x_2},{y_2}} \right)$ in $\mathbb R^2$, the following holds:

$\sqrt {{{\left( {{x_2} - {x_1}} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {{y_2} - {y_1}} \right)}^2}}  \le \left| {{x_2} - {x_1}} \right| + \left| {{y_2} - {y_1}} \right|$

Here is what came to my mind:

raising the right hand side to the power of 2 yields

${\left( {\left| {{x_2} - {x_1}} \right| + \left| {{y_2} - {y_1}} \right|} \right)^2} = {\left( {{x_2} - {x_1}} \right)^2} + {\left( {{y_2} - {y_1}} \right)^2} + 2\left| {{x_2} - {x_1}} \right|\left| {{y_2} - {y_1}} \right| \ge {\left( {{x_2} - {x_1}} \right)^2} + {\left( {{y_2} - {y_1}} \right)^2}$

Comment: Hint: Try to raise both sides to the power of $2$.

Comment: @Mark true. That would do it! then you will one excessive positive term on the RHS. Thanks !

Comment: This is just a special case of the triangle inequality. Consider the triangle with points $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_1, y_2)$, and $(x_2, y_2)$ and apply the triangle inequality.

Comment: The tag "solution verification" is to be used only when one actually includes a solution.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. “I want to prove this.” says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: Hypotenuse is always lower than sum of Cathetus!

Answer (score 1):

Draw the right triangle with vertices $(x_2,y_2), (x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_1)$. The hypotenuse is $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$. The legs of the triangle are $|x_2-x_1|$ and $|y_2-y_1|$. Hence, by the triangle inequality,
$$\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}\le |x_2-x_1|+|y_2-y_1|$$

*Exercise:* Find the equality case (Hint: The triangle inequality achieves equality when the triangle is degenerate).